ArgoCD Email Notifications: SMTP EOF Error (argocd failed to send email notification)
I'm encountering an issue with ArgoCD email notifications when trying to send notifications via SMTP using Gmail. Here's the error message I'm seeing in my logs:
This is the error i show in argocd-notification-controller:
time="2024-06-27T09:51:02Z" level=info msg="Sending notification about condition 'on-sync-succeeded.[0].zxM90Et6k4Elb1-fHdjtDJq0xR0' to '{gmail my-email@gmail.com}'" resource=argocd/email-poc
time="2024-06-27T09:51:13Z" level=error msg="Failed to notify recipient {gmail my-email@gmail.com} defined in resource argocd/email-poc: EOF" resource=argocd/email-poc
time="2024-06-27T09:51:13Z" level=info msg="Processing completed" resource=argocd/email-poc
Additional Context:

SMTP Configuration: I've configured ArgoCD to use Gmail's SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com) with port 465.

Certificate: The SSL/TLS certificate (fullchain.pem) used by ArgoCD (which is Let's Encrypt) is valid until August 28, 2024.


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified SMTP server settings and credentials.
Checked network connectivity from the server running ArgoCD to smtp.gmail.com.
Ensured SSL/TLS configuration is correct.

Could someone please help me understand why I'm receiving the EOF error when trying to send email notifications via ArgoCD? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
